# Small Excel spreadsheet loading very slowly using with Python, Pandas and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a program that is reading some data from an Excel spreadsheet (a small one: ~10 sheets with ~100 cells per sheet), doing some calculations, and then writing output to cells in a spreadsheet.

The program ran quickly until I modified to write its output into the same Excel file as where the input is read. Previously I was generating a new spreadsheet and then copying the output into the original file manually.

After the modifications the script's runtime jumped from a few seconds to about 7 minutes. I ran cProfile to investigate and got this output, sorted by cumulative runtime:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.001    0.001  440.918  440.918 xlsx_transport_calc.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000  437.926  437.926 excel.py:76(load_workbook)
        1    0.000    0.000  437.924  437.924 excel.py:161(_load_workbook)
        9    0.000    0.000  437.911   48.657 worksheet.py:302(read_worksheet)
        9    0.000    0.000  437.907   48.656 worksheet.py:296(fast_parse)
        9    0.065    0.007  437.906   48.656 worksheet.py:61(parse)
     9225   45.736    0.005  437.718    0.047 worksheet.py:150(parse_column_dimensions)
  9292454   80.960    0.000  391.640    0.000 functools.py:105(wrapper)
  9292437   62.181    0.000  116.213    0.000 cell.py:94(get_column_letter)
 18585439   20.881    0.000   98.832    0.000 threading.py:214(__exit__)
 18585443   58.912    0.000   86.641    0.000 threading.py:146(acquire)
 18585443   56.600    0.000   77.951    0.000 threading.py:186(release)
9293461/9293452   22.317    0.000   22.319    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
 37170887   15.795    0.000   15.795    0.000 threading.py:63(_note)
 21406059   13.460    0.000   13.460    0.000 {divmod}
 37170888   12.853    0.000   12.853    0.000 {thread.get_ident}
 18585447   12.589    0.000   12.589    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
 21408493    9.948    0.000    9.948    0.000 {chr}
 21441151    8.323    0.000    8.323    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
 18585446    7.843    0.000    7.843    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
...
...
...
```

Relevant code in the script:

```
...
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
...
xlsx = 'path/to/spreadsheet.xlsx'
...
def loadxlsx(fname, sname, usecols=None):
    with pd.ExcelFile(fname) as ef:
        df = ef.parse(sheetname=sname)
        if usecols:
            return [df.values[:,col] for col in usecols]
        else:
            return [df.values[:,col] for col in range(df.shape[1])]
...
data = loadxlsx('path/to/spreadsheet.xlsx')
...
<do computations>
...
book = load_workbook(xlsx)
<write data back to spreadsheet>
...
```

So according to the cProfile output the culprit appears to something within the call to `load_workbook`. Beyond that observation I'm a bit confused. Why are there 9000 calls to `parse_column_dimensions` and 18 million calls to various threading functions? And 9 million calls to `get_column_letter`?

This is the first time I have profiled any python scripts so I'm not sure if this output is normal or not... It seems to have some odd portions though.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's happening in the Pandas code but the number of calls is wrong. If you try simply opening the file with openpyxl and modifying the cells in place then it should be a lot faster so it looks like there is some unnecessary looping going on.